# Initialization of static variables in a class of utility functions

Tags: android

For my Android application, I have written a class which is composed of utility functions which are needed at various activites in the application.In this class, I need a context variable(for working with files) and an instance of preference manager and preference editor.Also, a long integer represnting the current date as a timestamp is needed:

```
private static long today;
private static Context myContext;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private static Editor editor;
```

Which is correct way to initialize these variables. I have tried doing it via a private constructor as shown below, but I am getting errrors.

```
private NetworkController()
{
    //Getting the Unix timestamp for today
    GregorianCalendar aDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar tDate = new  
    GregorianCalendar(aDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),aDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),  
    aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
    today = (tDate.getTimeInMillis())/1000; 
     //The preferences manager for reading in the preferences
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext);
    //The preferences editor for modifying the preferences values
    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
}
```

One approach would be to create an instance of this class in every activity where its used but I don,t want to do that.Any other approach is possible?

Comment: What errors, exactly, are you getting? Are you familiar with the idea of a *singleton*?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception related about sharedPrefs and editor.I am not familiar with this concept, thats why I am asking:)

Comment: Just a tip: be careful of your use of Context as a static variable.  This can very easily cause memory leaks.  Make sure it is nulled or dereferenced when you switch to a new Context.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of things that you use everywhere and only want one instance of, you can use what's called a [*singleton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). For example, here is a very simple one that holds an integer called `level`:

```
public class Utility {
    private static Utility theInstance;

    public int level;

    private Utility() {
        level = 1;
    }

    public static getUtility() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new Utility();
        }
        return theInstance;
    }

}
```

Then you can use this like:

```
Utility u = Utility.getUtility();
u.level++;
```

However, many people discourage the use of singletons, since they can lead to confusing program behaviour. A good article on this topic is [Singletons are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/). Singletons can be useful in some situations, but you should be aware of the traps involved in using them.

Comment: You answer is a bit confusing as you mix the Utility design pattern (only static methods, private constructor) with the singleton design pattern (a uniquely instanciated class with instance methods). Moreover, the singleton instance accessor is more standardly named getInstance and should be synchronized.

Comment: I'm not demonstrating the Utility pattern, that was just a name I chose based on the OP's wording. Notice that `level` is an instance variable; I could have added corresponding non-static getters and setters but didn't show that. And you can call the instance accessor anything you like, there's no requirement for it to be called `getInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Greg is right, just don't use any static stuff for what you want to do. There is no reason you don't want to have normal objects here. Pass the context as parameter and instanciate you objects when you need them to serve you :

```
private long today;
private Context myContext;
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private Editor editor;

public NetworkController( Context context )
{
    this.context = context;
    //Getting the Unix timestamp for today
    GregorianCalendar aDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar tDate = new  
    GregorianCalendar(aDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),aDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),  
    aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
    today = (tDate.getTimeInMillis())/1000; 
     //The preferences manager for reading in the preferences
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
    //The preferences editor for modifying the preferences values
    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
}
```

Singletons are a bad way of programming things, it makes things very hard to test. Even you don't yet use tests, don't use singletons, there lead to very poor quality code and real ball of muds when things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this:

```
public class NetworkController {

     SharedPreferences settings;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


     public NetworkController(Context context){
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = settings.edit();
     }

     public void saveName(String name){
          editor.putString("name", name).commit();
     }

     public String getName(){
          return settings.getString("name");
     }

     public static long getTimeStamp(){
          return System.currentTimeMillis();
     } 

}
```

You can use the class like below:

```
 NetworkController prefs = new NetworkController(context); // Context being an Activity or Application
 prefs.saveName("blundell");
 System.out.println(prefs.getName()); // Prints 'blundell';
 System.out.println(NetworkController.getTimeStamp()); // Prints 1294931209000
```

---

If you don't want to create an instance in every class you could create on instance in your Application and always reference that:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

     private NetworkController myPrefs;

     public NetworkController getPrefs(){
          if(myPrefs == null){ // This is called lazy initialization
             myPrefs = new NetworkController(this); // This uses the Application as the context, so you don't have issues when Activitys are closed or destroyed
          }
          return myPrefs;
     }

}
```

You need to add the `MyApplication` to your manifest:

```
<application 
    android:name="com.your.package.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

To use this single instance you would do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super(savedInstanceState);

          NetworkController prefs = ((NetworkController) getApplicationContext()).getPrefs();

          // use this object just like shown above
          prefs.saveName("blundell"); // etc
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a bunch of good suggestions posted here, but I suppose another approach for these kind of 'utility'/'helper' functions is to simply pass in the parameters you need the logic to work on. In your case, in stead of trying to make the logic work on a local `Context` reference, you could simply pass it in:

```
public static void NetworkController(Context context) {
    //Getting the Unix timestamp for today
    GregorianCalendar aDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar tDate = new  
    GregorianCalendar(aDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),aDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),  
    aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
    long today = (tDate.getTimeInMillis())/1000; 
    //The preferences editor for modifying the preferences values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    ...
}
```

The other variables you can calculate/deduce on the fly. It'll probably mean a bit more garbage collection, but should be relatively safe in terms of memory management.